# "com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ..." error when running emulator

Tags: java, android

I'm seeing many of these errors when using my emulator with IntelliJ.  I'm not sure what to do about it.  It doesn't appear to have been affecting anything, so I haven't paid much attention to it.  But I'm concerned it may cause an issue before long.

```
01-01 15:16:22.805: ERROR/StrictMode(607): null
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf0270 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
```

Comment: Are you using the Exchange service?  What's your question?

Comment: I supposed my question is, do I need to do something about this?  I'm not using the Exchange service.

Comment: Nothing to worry about.  It's a bug in the platform.  I believe it's an emulator thing but Googling should reveal more if you're curious.

Comment: These exceptions occur on any android emulator image that I have tried  no matter how it is started (command line, Idea, Eclipse). The images I tried exhibit this problem even without any additional applications installed (that is clean images straight from SDK). And I think that you should not close question just because this problem does not affect you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That answer does not solve the problem, only makes the symptoms go away. 
Try disabling host GPU in the Emulator options, it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This was already disabled for me and I still had the problem.  It was fixed for me by following this post...   http://stackoverflow.com/q/13765122/1246574