# radiogroup not working in android

Tags: android, radio-button

I have made a simple application in android with two activities,in 1st activity ,it's a form containing some editexts and radio group and a checkbox.but i have  problem with radio button.its value is not going to another activity.i have tried as below:

**act1.java**

```
   package com.example.myweb;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     public  String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myweb";
     Button b;
     EditText ed1,ed2,ed3,ed4;
     RadioGroup rg;
     RadioButton rb;
     CheckBox c1;
    // boolean yes = c1.isChecked();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);  
         b =(Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
         ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_msg);
         ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_msg1);
         ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_msg3);
         ed4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_msg4);
        // r1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        // r2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
         c1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ck1);
         int id=rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
         rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(id);
                 b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        // Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Act2.class);
                     Bundle b=new Bundle();
                     final String fname=ed1.getText().toString();
                     final String lname=ed2.getText().toString();
                     final String fon=ed3.getText().toString();
                     final String city= ed4.getText().toString();
                     final String gen = rb.getText().toString();
                     if(c1.isChecked()){



                                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Act2.class);

                                i.putExtra("Extra__fname", fname);
                                 i.putExtra("Extra__lname", lname);
                                 i.putExtra("Extra__fon", fon);
                                 i.putExtra("Extra__city", city);
                                 i.putExtra("gen", gen);
                                 startActivity(i);  
                    }
                    else{

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please accept it", 1).show();
                            }
                    }       
                     });
                    }
}
```

**act2.java**

```
  package com.example.myweb;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Act2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act2);
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        TextView t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        TextView t3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        TextView t4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv5);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

             String fname= bundle.getString("Extra__fname");
              String lname= bundle.getString("Extra__lname");
              String fon= bundle.getString("Extra__fon");
              String city= bundle.getString("Extra__city");
              String gen= bundle.getString("gen");
              t.setText(fname);
                t1.setText(lname);
                t2.setText(fon);
                t3.setText(city);
                t4.setText(gen);

                }
        }
```

**Logcat**

```
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf6fe0 that was originally bound here
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf6fe0 that was originally bound here
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-02 09:55:28.492: E/ActivityThread(554):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554): null
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf6fe0 that was originally bound here
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-02 09:55:28.592: E/StrictMode(554):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-02 09:55:28.592: W/ActivityManager(274): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@410f7970
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111677/com-android-exchange-exchangeservice-has-leaked-error-when-running-emulator. You are not getting null pointer exception now. create a new avd delete the old one. Try running with a new avd or a device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key should be the same

```
      i.putExtra("gen", gen);
```

Its

```
   String gen= bundle.getString("Extra_gen");
```

should be

```
   String gen= bundle.getString("gen");
```

Edit:

You are using getApplicationContext(). Instead use a activity context

```
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please accept it", 1).show();
```

To know when to use application context and when to use activity context, check the answer by commonsware in the below link

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

```
    Toast.makeText(act1.this, "Please accept it", 1).show();
```

Comment: still having problem...same problem..:(

Comment: when i run the projest it runs well,but when i click the button of 1st screen it displays "unfortunately your app stopped".

Comment: @user2334694 is it the same logvat that is posted now

Answer (score 1):

use

```
String gen= bundle.getString("gen");
```

instead of

```
String gen= bundle.getString("Extra_gen");
```

for retrieving selected `RadioButton` Value from Intent sended from previous Activity. because you are sending RadioButton Value with `gen` key but trying to retrieve it using `Extra_gen`

Comment: beat me to it by few seconds. :). +1

Comment: Hi, I think you are busy with your work, I haven't see you since 15 days. It is good that you are back

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String gen= bundle.getString("gen");
```

You need something like this

```
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
     void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rg, int checkedId) {
          for(int i=0; i<rg.getChildCount(); i++) {
               RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) rg.getChildAt(i);
               if(btn.getId() == checkedId) {
                    String text = btn.getText();
                    // do something with text
                    return;
               }
          }
     }
});
```

(OR)

When you need to get the selected radio option.

```
int id = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
if (id == -1){
     //no item selected
}
else{
if (id == R.id.radio_button1){
    //Do something with the button
}
}
```

Comment: i can't understand...what you say.

Comment: does not answer the question can post the same as comment

Comment: please see i have edited the code as per you said..but still having problem

Answer (score 0):

use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for radioGroup.

Sample code for `RadioGroup` which contains two `RadioButtons`

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {

            radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioGroup
                    .getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            if (radioButton.getText().equals("Name")) {
                // code for first radioButton
            } else {
                // code for second radioButton                  
            }
        }
    });
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: please see i have edited the code as per you said..but still having problem

Comment: What problem you are facing now?

Comment: when i run my app.the 1st activity shown,and after filling all details when i press button..it shows "Unfortunately your app stopped" in emulator.

Comment: post your logcat trace. And also try to use `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int radioButtonID = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View radioButton = rg.findViewById(radioButtonID);
int index = rg.indexOfChild(radioButton);
String gen="male";

if(index==0)
gen="male";
else
gen="female";

....

i.putExtra("gen", gen);
startActivity(i);
```

Make sure that in your `activity_main.xml`  male is having index 0.