# Android Emulator not working

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d2dce0 that was originally bound here
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d2dce0 that was originally bound here
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-19 17:24:50.606: E/ActivityThread(1334):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334): null
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d2dce0 that was originally bound here
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-19 17:24:50.656: E/StrictMode(1334):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-19 17:24:50.656: W/ActivityManager(886): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40f5a5e0

05-19 17:24:50.698: D/dalvikvm(1334): GC_CONCURRENT freed 401K, 20% free 2515K/3116K, paused 6ms+8ms, total 65ms
05-19 17:25:35.582: D/ExchangeService(1334): Received deviceId from Email app: null
05-19 17:25:35.582: D/ExchangeService(1334): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
05-19 17:25:40.616: D/ExchangeService(1334): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
05-19 17:25:40.626: D/ExchangeService(1334): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
05-19 17:25:40.626: D/ExchangeService(1334): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
05-19 17:25:40.636: W/ActivityManager(886): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
05-19 17:25:40.646: D/ExchangeService(1334): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
```

Comment: Honestly, android emulator rarely works. Crashes are almost a feature. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765122/various-android-logcat-errors

Comment: You are trying to launch an explicit intent to send a Mail and there is no Mail App installed on the Emulator

Comment: I wanted to create a button using android APIs. On clicking this button it should open compose of gmail. Can anyone tell how to do it or what is the code for it?

Answer (score 0):

This is only an emulator error, see this best answer for more details to solve the problem, the solution works for me:

[logcat errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765122/various-android-logcat-errors)