# three scrollviews inside framelayout

Tags: android, scrollview

I put three scrollviews inside framelayout and have three buttons. Each button is for each scrollview to set visibility.
I have error somewhere because scrollviews doesn't scrolling.

part of my `activity_main`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/darkoker" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/coffe"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/coffe"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:text="coffe" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/coffe_milk"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/milk_coffe"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:text="coffe milk" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tea"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tea"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="tea" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/hot_chocolate"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/coffe_cream"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:text="hot chocolate" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/orange"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/juice"
                android:text="orange juice" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/coca_colla"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/pepsi"
                android:text="coca-cola" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/beer"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/beer"
                android:text="beer" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

and part of my `MainActivity`

```
   ............
   final ScrollView frameLayout1=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll1);
    final ScrollView frameLayout2=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll2);
    final ScrollView frameLayout3=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll3);

    frameLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    frameLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    frameLayout3.setVisibility(View.GONE);      

           Button hotDrinks=(Button)findViewById(R.id.hot_drinks);
    hotDrinks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            frameLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            frameLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            frameLayout3.setVisibility(View.GONE);      
    }
    });
    Button juices=(Button)findViewById(R.id.juices);
    juices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            frameLayout1.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            frameLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            frameLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            frameLayout3.setVisibility(View.GONE);              
    }
    });

    Button alcohol=(Button)findViewById(R.id.alcohol);
    alcohol.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            frameLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            frameLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            frameLayout3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);               
    }
    });
```

and shows me this `error`

```
      ............
      05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721): null
      05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked:       Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection     com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0f808 that was originally    bound here
       05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
     05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
     05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
     05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
     05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
     05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
     05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
     05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
     05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
     05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
     05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
     05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
     05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    05-29 06:30:36.931: E/StrictMode(3721):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    05-29 06:31:27.221: E/ActivityThread(3721): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d65a88 that was originally bound here
    05-29 06:31:27.221: E/ActivityThread(3721): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d65a88 that was originally bound here
    05-29 06:31:27.221: E/ActivityThread(3721):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
   05-29 06:31:27.221: E/ActivityThread(3721):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
  05-29 06:31:27.221: E/ActivityThread(3721):   at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your asynctask doInBackground code.

Comment: what is `asynctask doInBackground code.`?

Comment: Oh I thought that service was yours. My bad.

Comment: Same service leak is posted on SO earlier. Check out the solution offered in this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13765122/786337

Comment: ok, I will try to test it on real device, because sometimes shows me error, sometimes doesn't. Is part of my `MainAplication` ok?