# Android sql database connection

Tags: java, android, sql, database, eclipse

I try to connect from eclipse emulator android to an sql server using this code:

```
String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://83.212.240.15:1521/hua;encrypt=fasle;user=xxxxxx;password=xxx;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
String username = "xxxxx";
String password = "xxxxx";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("insert into picture values('hi');");
conn.close();
```

but i have the following error

> Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cebcd0 that was originally bound here
>       android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d64ec0 that was originally bound here
>   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:969)

I have put the permission for internet and i also i have put the jtds-1.3.0.jar in lib folder.Any ideas?

Thanks in adnvanced

Comment: Please copy and paste the logcat. The image is not readable on my end.

Comment: i removed the picture

Comment: possible duplicate of [Various android logcat errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765122/various-android-logcat-errors)

Comment: I doubt it's the reason for your error, but `encrypt=fasle` does not look right.

Comment: Just a blind dumb guess without seeing any source, but did you unbind your email service connection in onstop?

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because you are using stmt.executeQuery.

stmt.executeQuery expects something in return (that means a result from a SELECT), but you are inserting data, not querying, so you should use stmt.executeUpdate instead