# Project not working on emulator

Tags: android

I have project which is running very fine on usb mode but when i run it on emulator it is not working. I am getting error unfortunately app has stopped working. I am using latest android emulator and i have also checked "Use Host GPU".

Logcat:

```
07-16 06:50:52.122: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-16 06:50:52.542: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-16 06:50:52.664: WARN/InputMethodManagerService(321): Focus gain on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40dcc670 (uid=10039 pid=1050)
07-16 06:50:52.882: INFO/ActivityManager(321): Displayed idtech.ESDN/.Map: +3s40ms
07-16 06:50:53.014: WARN/EGL_emulation(652): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-16 06:51:01.635: DEBUG/ExchangeService(856): Received deviceId from Email app: null
07-16 06:51:01.635: DEBUG/ExchangeService(856): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
07-16 06:51:06.722: DEBUG/ExchangeService(856): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
07-16 06:51:06.732: DEBUG/ExchangeService(856): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
07-16 06:51:06.732: DEBUG/ExchangeService(856): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
07-16 06:51:06.751: WARN/ActivityManager(321): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
07-16 06:51:06.751: DEBUG/ExchangeService(856): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
07-16 06:51:06.771: WARN/ActivityManager(321): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
07-16 06:51:06.881: ERROR/ActivityThread(856): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d33f58 that was originally bound here
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d33f58 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-16 06:51:06.922: ERROR/StrictMode(856): null
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d33f58 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-16 06:51:06.962: WARN/ActivityManager(321): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@411c3f00
07-16 06:51:06.971: DEBUG/dalvikvm(856): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 18% free 2446K/2964K, paused 73ms+5ms, total 184ms
07-16 06:51:06.982: ERROR/ActivityThread(856): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d34300 that was originally bound here
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d34300 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-16 06:51:07.012: ERROR/StrictMode(856): null
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d34300 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-16 06:51:07.024: WARN/ActivityManager(321): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@4126aaa0
07-16 06:51:30.692: INFO/Process(1050): Sending signal. PID: 1050 SIG: 9
07-16 06:51:30.875: INFO/ActivityManager(321): Process idtech.ESDN (pid 1050) has died.
07-16 06:51:34.702: INFO/ActivityManager(321): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=idtech.ESDN/.Startup} from pid 652
07-16 06:51:35.012: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-16 06:51:35.104: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1079): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
07-16 06:51:35.104: INFO/ActivityManager(321): Start proc idtech.ESDN for activity idtech.ESDN/.Startup: pid=1079 uid=10039 gids={50039, 3003, 1028}
07-16 06:51:35.354: INFO/dalvikvm(1079): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 9...
07-16 06:51:35.612: DEBUG/dalvikvm(321): GC_CONCURRENT freed 719K, 57% free 5724K/13064K, paused 32ms+59ms, total 793ms
07-16 06:51:35.632: ERROR/Trace(1079): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-16 06:51:36.352: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1079): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 66K, 8% free 2427K/2624K, paused 229ms, total 305ms
07-16 06:51:36.404: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(1079): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.935MB for 2560016-byte allocation
07-16 06:51:36.482: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1079): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 4926K/5128K, paused 70ms, total 70ms
07-16 06:51:36.554: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1079): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 4926K/5128K, paused 4ms+21ms, total 78ms
07-16 06:51:37.552: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1079): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 4926K/5128K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
07-16 06:51:37.594: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(1079): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.260MB for 4536916-byte allocation
07-16 06:51:37.732: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1079): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 9356K/9560K, paused 77ms+5ms, total 135ms
07-16 06:51:37.975: VERBOSE/PhoneStatusBar(796): setLightsOn(true)
07-16 06:51:37.982: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-16 06:51:38.142: DEBUG/(1079): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a19da80, tid 1079
07-16 06:51:38.894: INFO/ActivityManager(321): Displayed idtech.ESDN/.Startup: +3s823ms
07-16 06:51:40.922: INFO/ActivityManager(321): START u0 {cmp=idtech.ESDN/.Map} from pid 1079
07-16 06:51:41.372: VERBOSE/PhoneStatusBar(796): setLightsOn(true)
07-16 06:51:41.412: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-16 06:51:41.512: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-16 06:51:41.522: DEBUG/libEGL(1079): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
07-16 06:51:41.582: DEBUG/(1079): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a14a058, tid 1094
07-16 06:51:41.608: DEBUG/libEGL(1079): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
07-16 06:51:41.632: DEBUG/libEGL(1079): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
07-16 06:51:41.782: WARN/dalvikvm(1079): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-16 06:51:41.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1079): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 100
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config chosen
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:874)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
07-16 06:51:41.822: WARN/ActivityManager(321): Force finishing activity idtech.ESDN/.Map
07-16 06:51:42.782: WARN/ActivityManager(321): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40ffe8d8 u0 idtech.ESDN/.Map}
07-16 06:51:42.953: INFO/Choreographer(321): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-16 06:51:43.292: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-16 06:51:43.483: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-16 06:51:43.603: WARN/EGL_emulation(652): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-16 06:51:44.374: WARN/InputMethodManagerService(321): Focus gain on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4116d8a8 (uid=10039 pid=1079)
07-16 06:51:44.652: INFO/ActivityManager(321): Displayed idtech.ESDN/.Map: +3s485ms
07-16 06:51:51.839: DEBUG/ExchangeService(856): Received deviceId from Email app: null
07-16 06:51:51.839: DEBUG/ExchangeService(856): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
07-16 06:51:52.481: INFO/Process(1079): Sending signal. PID: 1079 SIG: 9
07-16 06:51:52.512: INFO/ActivityManager(321): Process idtech.ESDN (pid 1079) has died.
07-16 06:51:52.671: WARN/InputMethodManagerService(321): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1079 uid 10039
07-16 06:51:56.931: DEBUG/ExchangeService(856): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
07-16 06:51:56.941: DEBUG/ExchangeService(856): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
07-16 06:51:56.953: WARN/ActivityManager(321): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
07-16 06:51:56.961: DEBUG/ExchangeService(856): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
07-16 06:51:56.961: DEBUG/ExchangeService(856): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
07-16 06:51:56.981: WARN/ActivityManager(321): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
07-16 06:51:57.001: ERROR/ActivityThread(856): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cfa018 that was originally bound here
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cfa018 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-16 06:51:57.021: ERROR/StrictMode(856): null
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cfa018 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-16 06:51:57.035: WARN/ActivityManager(321): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@41023058
07-16 06:51:57.112: ERROR/ActivityThread(856): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cefef0 that was originally bound here
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cefef0 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-16 06:51:57.203: DEBUG/dalvikvm(321): GC_CONCURRENT freed 679K, 56% free 5766K/13064K, paused 11ms+13ms, total 156ms
07-16 06:51:57.233: ERROR/StrictMode(856): null
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cefef0 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-16 06:51:57.241: WARN/ActivityManager(321): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@416f86b0
```

Comment: Use the command "adb logcat" to know what's going on in the emulator, then let us know.

Comment: It's not working? What error does it gives? Please, be more specific.

Comment: just a guess maybe youre using an API that is not compatible with your project

Comment: Sir if there is an issue with API then it should also not run in my cell phone project is not running in emulator

Comment: whenever i run my project it gives an error "Unfortunately ESDN has stopped working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform few steps:

1) Using cmd do- `adb kill-server`

2) `adb start-server`

3) Create Device emulator again.

Still not seems ok then try this-

Quoting:

> Disable "Exchange Services" under Settings : Apps : All.

Kindly check the similar issues for the [various-android-logcat-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765122/various-android-logcat-errors).

Comment: I am using intellij idea IDEA and under settings option i cant find "Exchange Services"

Comment: i have done this thing also i have disable Exchange Services in emulator but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: @MuneemHabib - the paths have to be set to the directory where you installed the Android SDK and Java. Use the command prompt to confirm installation by typing in "java -version" and "javac -version".

Comment: I have typed "Java -version" but it is saying Java is not recognised as an internal or external command.

Comment: I dont think that there is an issue with manifest file it is because my project is running fine on hardware but it is not running on emulator. I think there is some issue with configuration

Comment: @Muneem Habib - manifest file is a configuration file for android. It contains all the required configuration to manage how your application will run in emulator and in real device. Check if you are using any library in manifest with the tag name `uses-library`.

Comment: No there is no tag name uses-library in android manifest file.

Comment: @MuneemHabib - Do you have the line `AccountManager.getAuthToken()` in your code ?

Comment: No sir i dont have any line AccountManager.getAuthToken() in my code.

Comment: @MuneemHabib - How are you handling Google Maps feature without a third party library as you don't have any uses-library attribute in your manifest. What's your <application> tag contains mainly?

Comment: Application tag contains <activity> and <intent filter> tags

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem whit my emulator, after the dialog error will appear press close button and go to apps and start the app from there. The app is installed but the emulator cant start because of an time out.
For the moment this is a way to test your app.

Answer (score 0):

check your device is it ARMv7 or ARMv6 few app did not work on ARMv6 and give the same error "unfortunately app has stopped working"

Comment: sir my device version is armv7