# Error displaying in the logcat

Tags: android, logcat

while running the emulator in log it is showing the Exchange service has leaked Serviceconnection[image]

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765122/android-emulator-spams-logcat-with-service-com-android-exchange-exchangeservice

Comment: By disabling "Exchange Services" in the emulated device under Settings  Apps  "All" tab.its worked for me

Comment: does it work for real devices too? if not, how it is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler fix is to disable "Exchange Services" in the emulated device under Settings : Apps : All.

`Reference` - [Android emulator spams logcat with "Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection ... that was originally bound here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765122/android-emulator-spams-logcat-with-service-com-android-exchange-exchangeservice)