# Exchange Service has leaked ServiceConnection, GridView Adapter

Tags: java, android, gridview, adapter

I am trying to get the contents of a grid view "reset" to their initial values. 
From my activity in on Create i have

```
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridv);
    gridView.setNumColumns(gridsize);

    gridView.setAdapter(new Adapter(this, temp,gridsize));
```

Then when i try to reset it , i did it like so (Call from another function in the Activity)

```
      gridView.setAdapter(new Adapter(this, temp,gridsize));
      gridView.invalidateViews();
```

It works but i get the following Error: (it doesnt crash )

```
10-22 18:12:39.719: E/ActivityThread(716): Service
com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection
com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cee170 that was 
 originally bound here
 10-22 18:12:39.719: E/ActivityThread(716): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service
com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection
com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cee170 that was originally bound here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app isn't com.android.exchange I assume, then you shouldn't worry. The reason is because you are using the emulator and logcat is printing errors from com.android.exchange too. A [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765122/android-emulator-spams-logcat-with-service-com-android-exchange-exchangeservice) has disscussed to disable this.

If this was on a real device. Please post device details.

Comment: It is in emulator , Thank you i thought i was doing something wrong , unfortunately i do not have a real device to test it on. Regards

Comment: Any chance you know for a "formal" process to actually remove first the contents of the grid view (of the adapter) and then initialize it again , Perhaps it would help

Comment: answer lies in adapter, but you need a different post for it, because question is compeletly different.